# Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'excerpt' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am newbie to **laravel** and was following a tutorial to create my first laravel website. Even though I follow everything correctly, I am currently facing this issue. I trie some solution found here but no satisfaction. Kindly help.[image]

My terminal

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you started a migration without this field and then added it to an existing migration. When you change the structure of DB, if the migration has already been run - you must either roll back this migration, or create a new one.

Try to run it in the console:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback --step=1
php artisan migrate
```